# not include file upload errors - Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Why is it when I don't include the file I get this

[IOException: can not replace a non-empty directory: Path(./public/upload)]

```
request.body.file("resourceFile").map { k =>
         val t = new java.io.File(s"./public/upload/${k.filename}")
         k.ref.moveTo(t, true)
         println("Ok File Upload" + k.filename)
```

How do you stop this from happening?

Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why it is happening.

You could add an ugly `if` statement to prevent the error :

```
request.body.file("resourceFile").map { k =>
         if (!k.filename.isEmpty) {
             val t = new java.io.File(s"./public/upload/${k.filename}")
             k.ref.moveTo(t, true)
             println("Ok File Upload" + k.filename)
         }
```